# AspNetUserManager: Tracking Error when adding and deleting Users

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-identity, .net-standard

i have an Issue when using the AspNetUserManager. If I add a User and delete the user (without recreating the Usermanager in between) I get this Error:

**System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: XXX}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.**

I have already set the "QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking" but it did not have any effect.

I am using the Usermanager in a WebForms application without dependency injection. So, I am creating the object "manually":

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : AspNetUserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private static UserStore<ApplicationUser, MyRole, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>  CreateUserStore(string connectionString)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>(); 
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);

            // IMPORTANT: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/10
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.usequerytrackingbehavior?view=efcore-3.1
            optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking); 

            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser, MyRole, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>(
                new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options)
                );
            return userStore;
        }
        public ApplicationUserManager(string connectionString)
            :base(
                 CreateUserStore(connectionString),
                 null,
                 new SqlPasswordHasher(), // custom hasher for old Membership passwords
                 new List<UserValidator<ApplicationUser>>() { new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>() },
                 null,
                 null,
                 null,
                 null,
                 null)
        {

        }
    }
```

In a normal MVC application I would try to configure "services.AddScoped<..>" as described here: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/48202403/instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-with-same-key-value-is-tracked

But I don't know how to do this in a WebForms application. Do you have any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I would like to add more information: In our code (legacy code) the ApplicationUser object that was used to create the user is copied and then returned. So if I want to delete it, I am deleting the copied object. Is it possible to "destroy" the old object? Or remove it from the tracking? Or do I have to use the original object every time? Can I just delete an user by ID?

```
var res = applicationUserManager.CreateAsync(user, "password").Result;
ApplicationUser userCopy = new ApplicationUser(user); // COPY
var res2 = applicationUserManager.DeleteAsync(userCopy).Result; // TRACKING EXCEPTION
```

**My Solution**
Get the user AGAIN (FindByIdAsync) and delete/update that user object!

Comment: any resolution to this?

Comment: I didnt check further. Too much legacy code that made a lot of things difficult. But the solution in the descrition was sufficient for me in that case. It is Entitify Framework specific. If the SW architecture is developed with EF in mind, then problems like this should not happen.